# degradation of sertraline

Tags: organic-chemistry, drugs, pharmacology

[image]

> The picture above is a drug called Setraline. Suggest a likely mode of degradation of sertraline hydrochloride alone in aqueous solution, giving likely structures of the degradation products.

From my knowledge, degradation in aqueous solution can only mean hydrolysis and sertraline does not contain hydrolysable groups like amide or ester. What are the other forms of degradation besides hydrolysis? in aqueous solution.

Comment: I agree.  I don't see anything happening quickly when sertraline is in a neutral aqueous solution.  That is, as long as the solution is protected from light.  Zoloft is photolabile and will decompose in the presence of light, see [here](http://omicsonline.org/open-access/environmental-fate-of-two-psychiatric-drugs-diazepam-and-sertraline-phototransformation-and-investigation-of-their-photoproducts-2157-7064.1000253.pdf).